# How to implement clean method that tell all images of my object have been loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, image, onload

Here is the code for "myObject"

```
function createContext(width, height,img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    if (img1!=null)
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img,0,0);
    return canvas.getContext("2d");
}

var myObject = function (){
    var self = this;
    this.width = squareWidth*5;
    this.height = squareHeight*5;
    this. x = 0;
    this. y = 0;
    this.draw = draw;
    function draw(ctx,x,y){
        imgData = self.ctx.getImageData(0,0,self.width,self.height);
        ctx.putImageData(imgData,x,y);
    }
    this.compute = compute;
    function compute(){
        self.ctx.drawImage(self.img2,(self.width-self.img2.width)/2+self.x,(self.height-self.img2.length)/2+self.y);
    }

    img1 = new Image();
    img1.src = "img1.png";
    img2 = new Image();
    img2.src = "img2.png";
    img1.onload = function (){
        img2.onload = function (){
            self.ctx = createContext(self.width, self.height,self.img1);
            self.compute();
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe use a handler that tell that all images have been loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you could try [when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) which supports this behaviour with then or done.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this :

```
var MyObject = function (){
    var self = this;
    this.width = squareWidth*5;
    this.height = squareHeight*5;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;

    img1 = new Image();
    img1.src = "img1.png";
    img2 = new Image();
    img2.src = "img2.png";

    img1.onload = function (){
        img2.onload = function (){
            self.draw = draw;   
            function draw(ctx,x,y){
                imgData = self.ctx.getImageData(0,0,self.width,self.height);
                ctx.putImageData(imgData,x,y);
            }
            self.compute = compute;
            function compute(){
                self.ctx.drawImage(self.img2,(self.width-self.img2.width)/2+self.x,(self.height-self.img2.length)/2+self.y);
            }
            self.ctx = createContext(self.width, self.height,self.img1);
            self.compute();
        }
    }
}
```

But it tells me "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'draw' " when I call :

```
var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.draw (ctx,0,0);
```

Maybe I have to use custom event but I don't know how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [*complete*](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/edits.html#dom-img-complete) can be of help to you

[image]
– http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/edits.html#dom-img-complete

> True if the browser has fetched the image, and it is in a supported
>   image type that was decoded without errors.

– https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

```
var myImages = document.images;
var len = myImages.length,i=0,bool=true;
for (;i<len;i++) {
    bool && myImages[i].complete;
}
console.log(bool);
```